# Second monitor can only display cursor

Tags: xorg, i3

Yesterday I installed Arch Linux with `xorg`, `nvidia` (no nouveau), `lightdm` and `i3`. With this setup I cannot get the second monitor to display/have windows. It can only display the cursor when dragging my mouse onto that screen, for which it display a cross instead of the regular cursor.

I run custom `i3` and `xorg` settings. I get the same behavior when running default configs for `i3`.

I did not have this issue when using the `i3`-edition of Manjaro. The difference in the `xorg`-config since then is that I have appended settings for my second screen, which seems to work in every other aspect except displaying windows.

How can I make my second monitor to be able to have windows?

One concern I have is that my Xorg-log outputs (my second monitor is connected via HDMI):

```
[     5.998] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event10)
[     5.998] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.998] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.998] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event11)
[     5.998] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.998] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.998] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event12)
[     5.998] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.998] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.999] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event13)
[     5.999] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.999] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.999] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 (/dev/input/event14)
[     5.999] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.999] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.999] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=12 (/dev/input/event15)
[     5.999] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.999] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     5.999] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event9)
[     5.999] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     5.999] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

This is my `xorg.conf`, for which I have problem displaying `Screen1`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1100 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol"          "auto"
    Option      "Device"            "/dev/psaux"
    Option      "Emulate3Buttons"   "no"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping"      "4 5"
    Option      "Sensitivity"       "0.3"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier      "Keyboard0"
    Driver          "kbd"
    Option          "XkbLayout"   "se,se"
    Option          "XkbVariant"  "nodeadkeys,"
    Option          "XkbOptions"  "grp:alt_caps_toggle"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier  "Monitor0"
    VendorName  "Unknown"
    ModelName   "HYO DUAL-DVI"
    ModeLine    "2560x1440_99"  400.00 2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync +vsync
    Option      "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL 2408WFP"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Device          "Device0"
    Monitor         "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option          "Stereo"                        "0"
    Option          "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder"       "DFP-0"
    Option          "SLI"                           "Off"
    Option          "MultiGPU"                      "Off"
    Option          "BaseMosaic"                    "off"
    Option          "IgnoreEDIDChecksum"            "DFP"
    Option          "UseEDIDDPI"                    "False"
    Option          "UseEDIDFreqs"                  "False"
    Option          "UseNvKmsCompositionPipeline"   "Off"
    Option          "ExactModeTimingsDVI"           "True"
    Option          "ModeValidation"                "AllowNonEdidModes,NoEdidMaxPClkCheck,NoVertRefreshCheck, NoHorizSyncCheck, NoMaxSizeCheck, NoMaxPClkCheck"
    SubSection      "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "2560x1440_99"
    EndSubSection
    Option "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: 2560x1440_99 +0+0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: 1920x1200 +0+0 {rotation=right, AllowGSYNC=Off}; HDMI-0: 1920x1200_60 +0+0 {rotation=right}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: Just to verify. Your Screen 1 (:0.1) is a black screen, and when you drag your mouse into it, the cursor appears as a cross or X. I've experienced similar behavior in RHEL 8 running my Xorg with separate X screens. I am continuing to investigate possible solutions and will definitely let you know if I find anything that works.

Comment: @Natolio Correct, thank you.