# Blank screen at startup, xset is unable to open display ""

Tags: linux, arch-linux, x11, i3, lightdm

Seemingly from out of nowhere, I get a blank screen during startup on Arch Linux. Going into the TTY shows me

```
xset:  unable to open display ""
Unable to connect to X server
```

I use X11, LightDM and i3. Here LightDM seems to be able to show a blank screen with a cross as a cursor (both during startup and after running `lightdm` in the TTY).

I suspect it can be can be caused of i3, since the file `~/.xsession-errors` has the content

```
i3status: trying to auto-detect output_format setting
i3status: auto-detected "i3bar"
i3status: exiting due to signal.
```

However, running `exec i3 -V -d all &>> "$HOME/i3.log"` only shows `i3: Cannot open display`, so perhaps its not i3.

When running `htop`, I can see that `Xorg` is running with command

```
/usr/lib/Xorg :0 -seat seat0 -auth /run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

which should tell me that the correct display indeed is `:0`. I tried `export DISPLAY=":0"`, but I don't know what to do after this.

I did update my system yesterday via pacman, could something there have caused this? I see that `i3wm` for Arch was updated a couple of days ago, which could explain it.

What should I do in order to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

It had nothing to do with neither i3 nor LightDM, it was only because of a bad configuration with X11.

My configuration, as can be seen in [my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644102/second-monitor-can-only-display-cursor), did not work with my secondary monitor, but worked as intended for my primary monitor. Now, all of a sudden, it seems like X11 identified my primary monitor as the secondary monitor in my configuration, even though I have not had the secondary one plugged in for about a half year.

So I simply removed everything in the config that was intended for my second monitor and now it works.